# Looping Gun Sounds Quantization

Tags: sound-design, video-games, game-audio

Just wanted to pick some brains here regarding the best way to approach looping gun sounds.  It will be my first time working with loops for game audio as opposed to either granular or polyphonic systems and am trying to find the best way forwards in regards to taking source field recordings + additional design of bursts or mag-dumps and converting those into rounds-per-minute/ms per round accurate loops for weapons in-game.

Pitching the entire loop obviously destroys the sound, although corrects the timing and cutting each segment of the burst or mag-dump then stitching back together quantized to, for example 100ms (for a 600rpm weapon) corrects the timing but loses the character and micro miss-timings of the original burst/dump recording and naturally only works going from lower rate of fire sources to higher rate of fire end product.

Does anybody have any good suggestions on how to conform my source recordings to the fire-rates required while still maintaining the original quality of the sound recorded and its inherent miss-timings during full-auto.

Anyway many thanks for any tips or pointers on this topic.

Comment: I note this is for video game audio. Is it necessary that the fire rate be variable in-game?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response, no the fire rates will be static for full auto weapons once the final rates of fire have been decided on per weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ableton! Then go to its inbuild granular synthesis of audio files and warp it with rythmical/transient algorithm. Check the transient marker and move them if needed. Then set the mode to -->|. (Looks like two arrows in default). So every gunshot is now played once. Then you can pitch it without quanticing or loosing pitch.

Other way is slice to Sampler and extract the groove template. Then you have Midi to work with.

Hope this helps as a starter!
Best,
Tobi

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I don't use Ableton but the workflow should be similar in Cubase so I will give that a try. Also extracting the groove template from the audio is another great idea, will definitely try that also. Many thanks!.